# Consultas lentas SQL Server Full-Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

He creado un catálogo para búsquedas Full-Text en SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[full_text](
[client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[file_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[page_number] [int] NULL,
[contents] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_full_text] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

create fulltext catalog dd_full_text;
GO

create fulltext index on full_text(contents)
key index PK_full_text on dd_full_text with change_tracking auto
GO
```

Uso la siguiente query como test:

```
SELECT *
FROM full_text
WHERE CONTAINS(contents, '"ban*" AND NOT "sab*"');
GO
```

Las primeras consultas son relativamente rápidas pero conforme transcurren los minutos se van ralentizando como muestro en la siguiente tabla:

Response Time ms

1. 2266
2. 3250
3. 3459
4. 11841 (tras 10 minutos)
5. 15391

Durante las pruebas no he insertado nuevas filas, por lo que no comprendo porque cada vez las consultas tardan más en devolver los resultados.

Comment: El problema tambien radica en el tipo de dato nvarchar el cual es el doble de pesado generando mas lentitud en la consulta a mi me esta pasando

Answer (score 1):

por problemas de performance pueden afectar muchas variables, necesitarias agregar al problema por lo menos version de SQL Server, sistema operativo, si ademas del SQL Server existen otras aplicaciones corriendo en el/los servidores, estado de recursos del servidor  % proc, % uso disco, % memoria y espacio libre en todos los discos, contadores de performance monitor en cada ejecución, alguna traza, etc.. . Saludos